# How to check whether a method returns a null?

Tags: java, junit, jmock

```
Assert.assertThat(refVar.method(), is(null));
```

Does the code is(null) correct to check whether the refVar.method() returns a null?
If not, how do i check whether something is a null or not?
I've tried aNull but the IDE says this method does not exist, i tried importing Matcher.* already.
Please help.

Comment: Do you want to check that `refVar.method()` is returning `null` when called in your unit test method directly or do you want to check if `refVar.method()` is returning `null` at some point during a test range setup with jMock (like with `assertIsSatisfied()`)?

Comment: I want to check whether the refVar.method() is returning null. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @Progman forgot to mention you here too..

Answer (score 0):

***Null or Not Null***

The matchers `aNull<T>(Class<T>)` and `aNonNull<T>(Class<T>)` specify that an argument is `null` or is `not null`, respectively.

The following code specifies that the method "doSomething" must be called with two `strings`, the first must be `null` and the second must be  `not null`.

```
oneOf (mock).doSomething(with(aNull(String.class)), aNonNull(String.class)));
```

Check this [jMock Matchers](http://jmock.org/matchers.html) for more clarifications

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that jMock is not the right tool to do this. Mocks are usually used to have some kind of dummy implementation of some class/interfaces instead of having the actual production implementation of some class/interface in your unit tests. With jMock you write code like:

> When method `foo` is called with the argument `42`, the mock of that object/interface should return the string `"abc"`.

However, jMock does not check if an existing class will return the value you expect. That is something "basic" JUnit tests will do. So you instance the class you want to check and call the methods you want to verify that it does indeed return the values it should return. So you write something like:

```
Assertions.assertNull(refVar.method());
```

This will verify that the return value of the `refVar.method()` call right there will return `null`. There is no need for jMock here.